# Google Apps Script, spreadsheet, taking too long to run

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using an `onEdit()` function that checks which cell in which sheet has been changed to run the appropriated routine.
When the changed cell is in `sheet1` and is not the `I3` it should run a simple routine, but it is taking too long.
Here is the code:

```
if (sheet === 'sheet1'){    
if (changedCell != 'I3') {
         var row = e.source.getActiveRange().getRow();
         var cont = row-6;
         var column = e.source.getActiveRange().getColumn();
         var Relatorio = ss.getSheetByName("RELATÓRIOS_ACOMPANHAMENTO");
         var edit = Relatorio.getRange(row, column);
         var coluna = Relatorio.getRange(5, column).getValue();
         var linha = Relatorio.getRange(row, 15).getValue();
         var baseAcom = ss.getSheetByName("EVENTOS_PARTICIPANTES");
         var editbase = baseAcom.getRange(linha, coluna);
         edit.copyTo(editbase, {contentsOnly: true});
    }
}
```

When I check the spreadsheet, it does what i want to do very fast, but it stays showing the calculating formulas bar for almost 1 min, and I can't perform any other functions until it ends.
Is there a way for me to speed it up?

Comment: Hi! Does script is slow even just one cell is changed?

Comment: Exactly, it takes almost one minute for every cell I change.

Comment: Check out the [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices), this might help you speed up or improve the performance of your script like: Minimize calls to other services, Use batch operations, Avoid libraries in UI-heavy scripts and Use the Cache service. Hope this helps!